# Why am I getting FileNotFoundException in Windows phone 8 using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to check my db file existence in try block and in catch I am creating it.

```
public async Task<bool> CheckDbAsync()
{
    bool dbExist = true;
    try
    {
        StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(DB_NAME);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,"baby.db") , true);
        dbExist = false;
    }

    return dbExist;
}
```

Issue is I am getting same handled exception. Code breaks on my try block. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using

```
System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DB_NAME));
```

which returns a bool if file exists or not.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check file existance, you can use TryGetItemAsync() like this:

```
StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(DB_NAME);
```

Comment: @ RenDishen. I am not able to use TryGetItemAsync. Getting eror that 

"windows.storage.storgaefolder does not contain defination of TryGetItemAsync"